# Why does my website have a horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I have a horizontal scroll bar on three on my seven pages, and I do not understand why. At first, I thought it was because of my footer, so I changed the footer to make sure that wasn't the issue. Changing the footer fixed my landing page, but did not fix the three below:

[home](http://www.thebowmanwedding.ca/home.html), [story](http://www.thebowmanwedding.ca/story.html), [venue](http://www.thebowmanwedding.ca/venue.html)

I have looked through, and my style.css is the only style sheet I have, and I cannot find the issue. any assistance would be appreciated.

I have not found anywhere where I have `width=100%` or anything like that. I have read a few other post, and haven't found any blatantly obvious things that are wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the markup of the footer. Container comes outside row not inside.

```
<footer>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="container">
```

to

```
<footer>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
```

Comment: Wow. I don't know why that worked on some of the pages and not others, but that sure did fix it. I have been looking at this code way too long. Thanks!